# Trying to reproduce an unusual table

Tags: tables

I'm a LaTeX beginner. I know (somewhat) how to make a traditional table but I cannot figure out how to reproduce this table.
[image: table 1]

I would very much appreciate if someone could show me how this kind of table is drawn. Thank you!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{ftnxtra}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{tabu}


\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\linespread}{1.1mm}

\begin{table}[t]{\textbf{Table 1}\\}

\begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | p{2.25cm} |}

\hline
Country & Survey Year & 1 Percent Tax on Wealthiest 10 Percent of Households & Progressive Tax Rate Schedule: 1 Percent on Top 10 Percent and Additional 1 Percent on Top 5 Percent \\

\hline

\hline Canada & 1999 & 0.6 & 1.1 \\ 

\hline Germany & 2006 & 1.1 & 2.0 \\ 

\hline Italy & 2004 & 1.0 & 1.7 \\ 

\hline Japan & 2003 & 1.2 & 2.0 \\

\hline United Kingdom & 2000 & 0.8 & 1.3 \\ 

\hline United States & 2006 & 1.1 & 3.1 \\ 

\hline Unweighted Average & \textemdash & 1.1 & 1.9 \\ 

\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please do not use ``` for each line, mark the whole code and press `CTRL+K` then. There's also an `\end{table}` missing. Do you really need to change the linespread?

Comment: If you know where to break the lines, just enter them in column order.  Another trick is to use \multicolumn for only one column (to change l to p).

Comment: Oh, and you can also use \parbox[b] inside the tabular.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two ways — breaking lines in cells with the `makecell` package; we also can give a common formatting, alignment, &c. to  cells introduced by the commands `\thead` and `\makecell`. Btw, you shouldn't set both `\parskip` and `\parindent` to a non-zero value. Also, `\linespread` is a *factor*, not a length.

With vertical lines:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font ={bf, sf}}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{ftnxtra}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
  \sffamily\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
  \caption{A first table}
  \begin{tabular}{ | l | *{3}{c|} }
    \hline
    Country & Survey Year & \thead{1 Percent Tax on Wealthiest & \\ 10 Percent of Households} & \thead{Progressive Tax Rate Schedule:\\ 1 Percent on Top 10 Percent and\\ Additional 1 Percent on Top 5 Percent} \\
    \hline\noalign{\vskip0.667ex}
    \hline
    Canada & 1999 & 0.6 & 1.1 \\
    \hline
    Germany & 2006 & 1.1 & 2.0 \\
    \hline
    Italy & 2004 & 1.0 & 1.7 \\
    \hline
    Japan & 2003 & 1.2 & 2.0 \\
    \hline
    United Kingdom & 2000 & 0.8 & 1.3 \\
    \hline
    United States & 2006 & 1.1 & 3.1 \\
    \hline
    Unweighted Average & \textemdash & 1.1 & 1.9 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without vertical lines, using `booktabs`: in the opinion of many, it looks more professional:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font ={bf, sf}, singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{ftnxtra}

\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
  \sffamily\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
  \caption{A first table}
  \begin{tabular}{ @{\,}l *{3}{c}@{\,} }
    \toprule
    Country & Survey Year & \thead{1 Percent Tax on Wealthiest \\ 10 Percent of Households} & \thead{Progressive Tax Rate Schedule:\\ 1 Percent on Top 10 Percent and\\ Additional 1 Percent on Top 5 Percent} \\
    \midrule
    Canada & 1999 & 0.6 & 1.1 \\
    Germany & 2006 & 1.1 & 2.0 \\
    Italy & 2004 & 1.0 & 1.7 \\
    Japan & 2003 & 1.2 & 2.0 \\
    United Kingdom & 2000 & 0.8 & 1.3 \\
    United States & 2006 & 1.1 & 3.1 \\
    \addlinespace
    Unweighted Average & \textemdash & 1.1 & 1.9 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This version uses manual line breaks.  Not sure why you want to use all these packages and not use booktabs.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{comment}
%\usepackage{ftnxtra}
%\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\linespread}{1.1mm}
\begin{table}[t]
\caption{}
\tiny
\centering\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|}
\hline
 &&& Progressive Tax Rate Schedule: \\
 && 1 Percent Tax on Wealthiest & 1 Percent on Top 10 Percent and \\
Country & Survey Year &  10 Percent of Households & Additional 1 Percent on Top 5 Percent \\
\hline
Canada & 1999 & 0.6 & 1.1 \\ 
Germany & 2006 & 1.1 & 2.0 \\ 
Italy & 2004 & 1.0 & 1.7 \\ 
Japan & 2003 & 1.2 & 2.0 \\
United Kingdom & 2000 & 0.8 & 1.3 \\ 
United States & 2006 & 1.1 & 3.1 \\ 
\hline
Unweighted Average & \textemdash & 1.1 & 1.9 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: table]